# HP z840 won't boot post install

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, ssd

I'm building a VM server on an HP z840 workstation.   The install from USB appears to go fine, but once I reboot, I continue to get the message that I need to install an operating system on the hard disk.

In the system I've got a 256G SSD and a 4T HD connected to the integrated LSI SAS controller, as that is where the internal bays connect.  I'm investigating whether or not I can switch to using the internal SATA connections instead.

The SSD via the SAS controller is visible as a boot option, but it simply will not boot.

I have the UEFI option disabled in the boot menu, and secure boot disabled as well.

I've not had much luck finding anything online that would help.  Hopefully someone here has run into this before and has a suggestion, as the hardware was pretty good buy for the capacity I wanted, and overall it seems like a very well built machine.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  I finally managed to get it to install.  After getting a UEFI capable video card, I enabled secure boot, then install Ubuntu to the SSH again, still connected to the SAS controller.

After that install the system boots correctly.